# Search function displaying results at the index in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

how can I display the results of my query from the search function in the index view? Apparently, the search works fine from what is displayed at the default cake bottom area.
    SELECT `Movie`.`movie_id`, `Movie`.`title`, `Movie`.`date`, `Movie`.`description` FROM `cTrader`.`movies` AS `Movie` WHERE `Movie`.`date` <= 20141118. 
So, I was wondering on how to display all my posts (movies) based on the date search in the index.ctp
Thanks in advance, Andrew

THE VIEW:

```
<h1>Movies</h1>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Movie', array('type' => 'get', 'action' => 'search'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('date', array(
    'type'  => 'date',
    'label' => 'Date',
    'empty' => false,
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'minYear'=>'1990',
    'maxYear'=>date('Y'),
     ));  ?>

 <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Description</th>
   </tr>
<?php foreach ($movies as $movie): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $movie['Movie']['title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $movie['Movie']['date'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $movie['Movie']['description'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($movie); ?>
</table>
<ul>
   <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Insert a new movie'), array('controller' => 'movies', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
</ul>
```

THE CONTROLLER

```
<?php
class MoviesController extends AppController {

public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

public function index() {
$this->set('movies', $this->Movie->find('all'));
}

    public function view($movie_id = null) {

        if (!$movie_id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $movie = $this->Movie->findById($movie_id);
        if (!$movie) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $this->set('movie', $movie);
    }


public function search() {

 if (!isset($this->request->query['date'])) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }
    $result = $this->request->query['date']['year'] . $this->request->query['date']['month'] .     $this->request->query['date']['day'];
    $searchdate = array(
        'Movie.date <=' => $result,
        );
    $this->set('movies', $this->Movie->find('all', array('conditions' => $searchdate )));
    $this->view = 'index';
    }
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: I would not reinvent the wheel and simply use https://github.com/CakeDC/search/ - which does exactly that but in a clean DRY way.

Comment: **Andrew**, can you explore exact problem that you face or where you get error??

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @Supravat actually the function reacts fine and its processing accordingly. However, my problem occurs after my first search. For example I search my first movie based on date and is being displayed but when I search again it displays all my records and that is happening I guess because something needs to be cleared. What would that be? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form to the following

```
<h1>Movies</h1>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Movie', array('type' => 'get', 'action' => 'index'));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('date', array(
    'type'  => 'date',
    'label' => 'Date',
    'empty' => false,
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'minYear'=>'1990',
    'maxYear'=>date('Y'),
     ));  ?>

 <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Description</th>
   </tr>
<?php foreach ($movies as $movie): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $movie['Movie']['title'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $movie['Movie']['date'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $movie['Movie']['description'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($movie); ?>
</table>
<ul>
   <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Insert a new movie'), array('controller' => 'movies', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
</ul>
```

And your controller to following.

```
<?php
   class MoviesController extends AppController {

  public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

  public function index() {
     if(isset($this->request->query['date']){
             $result = $this->request->query['date']['year'] . $this->request->query['date']['month'] .     $this->request->query['date']['day'];
              $searchdate = array(
             'Movie.date <=' => $result,
          );
         $this->set('movies', $this->Movie->find('all', array('conditions' => $searchdate )));
         $this->render = 'search';
     }
     else{
         $this->set('movies', $this->Movie->find('all'));
     }
  }
```

?>